# Resharper in VS not reformatting section of code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper, resharper-9.0

I've recently reinstalled resharper and have kept as many of my original VS settings as possible, including short cut keys. I'm trying to use coding conventions as [specified by MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx).
I have a list as a class member and `ctrl + K, ctrl + D` will not do anything to it. It compiles, no errors, runs as it is supposed to, I just cannot it to reformat.

[image]

An abridged version of the list follows:

```
public static List<MyList> MyLists => new List<MyList>
{
    new MyList()        {
        Name = "name1",
        Categories = new List<Category>()
        {
            new Category() {Name = "fee"},
            new Category() {Name = "fi"}
        }},
        new MyList()
{
        Name = "name2",
        Categories = new List<Category>()
        {
            new Category() {Name = "fo"},
            new Category() {Name = "fum"}
            }
    }
};
```

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a setting that may apply to this type of formatting.

Okay so it reformats with `Ctrl + E, F` but not `ctrl + K, ctrl + D`, so why doesn't `ctrl + K, ctrl + D` work on this code?

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the correct shortcut? In R# it's Ctrl+E,F afaik.

Comment: Maybe it's just a subset of formattings, and the other files contains such code, that will be affected by them.